# iOS - Webview - Notify Javascript when an NSNotification is received

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, uiwebview

I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this. I have a bunch of NSNotifications and I'd like to create listeners in Javascript, embedded in a UIWebView, that will get executed when the NSNotifications are received.

I know this is possible using PhoneGap and the method sendPluginResult, but I was wondering if there was another way of doing it without cordova.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your listener outside the `UIWebView` and send the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` message to your web view.

```
- (void)registerObserver
{
    NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        @"FirstNotification", @"SecondNotification", @"ThirdNotification", nil];

    for (NSString *name in names)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
            addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(notificationReceived:)
                   name:@"NotificationName"
                 object:nil];
    }
}

- (void)notificationReceived:(NSNotification *notification)
{
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"notificationReceived('%@');", notification.name];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the call back NSNotification method call this:

```
[yourwebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"methodName()"];
```

and create that "methodname" in your javascript code